# How to create an internal search engine for objects

Tags: c#, list, search, object, razor

Hi I'm to create an internal search engine at my `.cshtml` website.

The engine is going to search through a list of objects. And is going to return a list based on the search criteria.

The returned list is ordered by how many times the search words are in the object, and if it's in the header of the object.

The object has a `header` and `content` that's gonna be searched through. Both are strings.

My question is how do go about this in the most efficient way, cause I'm thinking a lot of loops and temporary lists. But that would take a lot of response time. Would it be better with a binary search, and how?
Or if there is an application already out there that can this, and that allows me to design the output myself.

PS: All the objects are from a database if that helps.

Comment: Are `header` and `content` simple string properties?

Comment: If you are worried about performance, this is best done in the database. SQL Server has a full-text search component that can make things simpler.

Comment: Also, a binary search would be for data that is sorted - like an index. I don't think that this is applicable here.

Comment: You can get the list itself with simple `LIKE`s. Sorting might be a bit more difficult. Don't know if sorting on the database side with something like `(LEN(ColumnToCheck) - LEN(REPLACE(ColumnToCheck,"theSearchTerm","")))` (you only want it for sorting, if you want the actual number of occurences, you'd need to divide by `LEN("theSearchTerm")`) would be faster than sorting on the application side with something like `Regex.Matches(ColumnToCheck, "theSearchTerm").Count`.

Comment: Yes. Both property are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to razor nor ASP.net, but in C# with a list of objects, it can be done giving a weight to each object based in your searchpattern and order the list by weight:

```
 var searchPattern = "word1|word2";
 var regex = new Regex(searchPattern);
 var search = list.Select( o => 
                        new { Weight = regex.Matches(o.Header).Count * 20 
                                     + regex.Matches(o.Content).Count * 10, 
                              Value = o})
                  .OrderByDescending(o => o.Weight);
```

This can be rewriten as an sql query if you have the objects in a database, seems that sql server LIKE support regex expressions.

Comment: How would the sql for that look like

Comment: I've tried this, but I get all the objects in, what seems a random order. But what if I want only to show a list of objects which have words from my search

Comment: I'm not enough proefficient with sql, but I'll try to create the query. If you want yo show only the objects that have words add .Where(o => o.Weight>0)

Comment: It works! nice. For other noobs like me, I will add that you need `namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions` for the `Regex` and that the `Regex.Matches` is case sensitive ^^